# How to save a tensor to TFRecord?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to save a tensor to the TFRecord format. I tried this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[2.0, 3.0, 3.0],
                 [1.0, 5.0, 9.0]], dtype='float32')

x2 = tf.io.serialize_tensor(x)

# I understand that I can parse it using this:
# x3 = tf.io.parse_tensor(x2, 'float32')

record_file = 'temp.tfrecord'
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(record_file) as writer:
    writer.write(x2)
```

It gives me the error:

```
TypeError: write(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: tensorflow.python._pywrap_record_io.RecordWriter, record: str) -> None
```

I understand it's probably a basic question but I read a guide on TensorFlow site and searched in StackOverflow but didn't find the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use the actual value of your tensor `x2`, not the tensor object itself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[2.0, 3.0, 3.0],
                 [1.0, 5.0, 9.0]], dtype='float32')
x2 = tf.io.serialize_tensor(x)
record_file = 'temp.tfrecord'
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(record_file) as writer:
    # Get value with .numpy()
    writer.write(x2.numpy())
# Read from file
parse_tensor_f32 = lambda x: tf.io.parse_tensor(x, tf.float32)
ds = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset('temp.tfrecord')
      .map(parse_tensor_f32))
for x3 in ds:
    tf.print(x3)
# [[2 3 3]
#  [1 5 9]]
```

In recent versions of TensorFlow there is a currently experimental [`tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/TFRecordWriter) to do this too:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[2.0, 3.0, 3.0],
                 [1.0, 5.0, 9.0]], dtype='float32')
# Write to file
ds = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x)
      .map(tf.io.serialize_tensor))
writer = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter('temp.tfrecord')
writer.write(ds)
# Read from file
parse_tensor_f32 = lambda x: tf.io.parse_tensor(x, tf.float32)
ds2 = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset('temp.tfrecord')
       .map(parse_tensor_f32))
for x2 in ds2:
    tf.print(x2)
# [[2 3 3]
#  [1 5 9]]
```

Comment: I get the error 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' any suggestion?